# How to specify the location of a header file when building a shared library

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I have two folders, each containing a .c .h and makefile. They are libraries and when I build them they produce a .so file.

I want to include one header file in the other header file.

When I am building it with the make file how do I tell it that the header file is in the other folder? Do I specify it in the makefile?

This is on ubuntu.

This is the makefile.

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-c -Wall -Werror -fPIC 

APP1 = tca

all: $(APP1) 

$(APP1): $(APP1).c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(APP1).c $(LIBS)
$(CC) -shared -o lib$(APP1).so $(APP1).o
sudo cp $(APP1).h /usr/include/ 
sudo cp lib$(APP1).so /usr/lib/
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib/lib$(APP1).so
sudo ldconfig
sudo ldconfig -p | grep $(APP1)

clean:
rm -rf *.o
rm -rf *.so
rm -rf $(APP1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the project directory structure is something like this:

```
./project_dir
  |-src/      //< Source code folder
  |-include/  //< Folder containing header files
  |-Makefile  //< Makefile for the project
```

Add these change's in the Makefile:

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -I ./include

APP1 = tca

all: $(APP1) 

$(APP1): $(APP1).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(APP1).c $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -shared -o lib$(APP1).so $(APP1).o
    sudo cp ./include/$(APP1).h /usr/include/ 
    sudo cp lib$(APP1).so /usr/lib/
    sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib/lib$(APP1).so
    sudo ldconfig
    sudo ldconfig -p | grep $(APP1)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf *.so
    rm -rf $(APP1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it inside the files only. The place where you are placing your makefile will be your main directory. Now suppose you have two directory A and B and each contain one header file and you need to include these header files. In main directory where ever you want to include header file, just provide the path like this

```
#include "../A/header_name.h" //If dir A is on just outside main dir.
#include "./B/header_name.h"  //If dir B is on inside the main dir.
```

Similarly,you can include files individually. 
If you want to include through makefile the after `cc` command you can add `-idirafter ../A/` parameter. I have not tried through makefile, but this works on command line.So, probably it will work. Let me know :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is how to tell to your compiler (since what make is doing is just to fire a command line) where the header is.
More specifically, it is the job of the preprocessor.

With gcc, you have two options to do that : `-I dir` and `-iquote dir`
The former will add dir to the search path for every #include directive found during the preprocessing, the latter only for the #include directive using quotes.

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) is the documentation about these options.